# Backing Up Large File with Small Changes

Tags: windows, copy

I have a large file that is backed up to a USB drive. Can I avoid having to copy the entire file each time a small change is made? I need something like rsync, but for Windows and without the need for client/server and the network. Does something like that exist?

Comment: It's a good question IMHO - at least I'd like to know. It's called delta copy. And there's [this free client and server](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) which does rsync. Both can be installed [on the same machine](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/rsync-for-windows-deltacopy/) apparently.
I don't consider this as an answer as I didn't provide you with detailed instructions, and didn't test it... @josh

Comment: Not sure I'd try using any tool for incremental copy of a single file: in order to *verify* that *all* changes were written, one would have to diff the two files, which would take as long as writing the whole file again.